# Draw CSliderCtrl's channel in mfc

Tags: mfc

I want to implement a video player using CSliderCtrl which displays playing and downloading progress. the thumb moves as video plays, while the channel changes as video file downloads. I refer to this article [1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8985/Customizing-the-Appearance-of-CSliderCtrl-Using-Cu), but the channel only can be draw in the event handler, however, i want to draw the channel when receives a bulk of file. so i want to know how can i retrieve the channel at runtime rather than in the handler.
[image: effect]

Answer (score 1):

As with other owner-drawn controls you need to draw everything on the Custom Draw even handler. This custom class on Codeproject is no exception.

In order to accommodate this you would need to create a member variable in the parent window that will hold the size of already downloaded chunk as well as the size of the file. E.g.

```
class CMyDialog: CDialog
{
private:
   int nBytes; // downloaded bytes
   int nSize;  // total size of the file
}
```

When you receive a chunk you would increment the nBytes accordingly.

In your Custom Draw handler for the slider control you would use these variables to offset the channel position. Basically, as the author of the article suggested you just draw the rectangle. The author used one rectangle, you would use two (left and right rectangles) drawn with the different brushes

The actual trick is to force the slider to redraw each time you receive the chunk. You need to use [Invalidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ax04k970%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
m_myslider.Invalidate();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! I have tried using Invalidate(), but it doesn't work. the OnCustomdraw() handler seems not being invoked each time when calling Invalidate().

Comment: Try calling invalidate for the whole window